# JPanel dimension auto changes

Tags: java, swing, dimension

I have the following class:

```
public class Projector extends JPanel{
  public Projector(){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 704));
  }
}
```

If I print Projector's dimension inside the constructor, I have the right dimension, but when I print the dimension somewhere outside the constructor, 
I get as result (1018, 675)

any ideas why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: This code won't compile, you're missing an `)` on `this.set...`. *but when I print the dimension somewhere outside the constructor* How are you printing it? Please post a [Runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: common, this is just a typo.. this.getSize().toString() is how I get the dimension

Comment: Again, please read the link I provided and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/) that we can copy paste and see the same issue you see. *common, this is just a typo..* I have seen tons of questions here that didn't worked because of a typo...

Comment: `preferredSize` is only a hint, which layout managers are allowed to ignore.  Are you taking the size of the component or the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Java doesn't count the pixels used for the Window border that your OS draws, including where the Minimize, Maximize and Close buttons are. (That's why the difference is bigger on the Y axis)
There's another method to get the pixels wasted because of this.